# Почему у меня не компилируется программа в CodeLite

Tags: c, ide, компилятор, codelite

Когда я запускаю программу на C в CodeLite выводит просто: Press any key to continue

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы определитесь: "я запускаю программу" или "не компилируется программа"?

Comment: Моя программа запускается и компилируется но, программа пишет: Press any key to continue, и всё.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос в английской версии SO: [CodeLite - Console runs but code is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977112/codelite-console-runs-but-code-is-not-working) и там топикстартер решил проблему путём отключения антивирусника (Касперсий), который, по всей видимости, удалял exe файл сразу после компиляции. Похоже на какой-то баг в CodeLite, которая запускает консоль, не убедившись, что ей есть что выполнять. А пауза и надпись появляется из-за включённой опции `Project settings - General - Pause when execution ends`.